# What are the wavy conductive tracks for?

Tags: pcb

Consider the following PCB.

[image]

I notice some motherboards have such wavy tracks. Are there any purposes?
Or it is there merely for artistic purposes?

Comment: Matched-length traces are very much not artistic. Either these are differential pairs, or they are matched length for timing purposes.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Thank  you. It is nice to know this. :-)

Comment: I see only one differential pair in the image. These are most definitely done to match lengths.